# Building simple program in eclipse, but won't run because of fragment_main

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I'm using the tutorial off of the developers site on Android and I can't get it to run because of fragment main: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html <- that tutorial. I don't know what to do with fragment main! I get error after error no matter what I do with it. Any help here? I'm using a Mac running Lion. It also did this to me on Linux and it's frustrating.

The tutorial mentions nothing of fragment_main and if I build the project without a main activity, I'm missing half of what I need, and if I delete fragment_main.xml I get more errors. Sorry for the dummy question. I can't find answers anywhere to this.

Help please?

These are the errors I get

```
[2014-03-29 15:33:58 - FirstApp] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-03-29 15:33:58 - FirstApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-03-29 15:33:58 - FirstApp] Launch canceled!
[2014-03-29 15:59:19 - FirstApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2014-03-29 16:14:27 - FirstApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

Here's MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new      PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want to change your `ActionBarActity` to `Activity` I guess ?

Comment: No idea, I just want it to run without fragment_main.. or figure out how to use fragment_main so it'll run with it.

Comment: Can you post `MainActivity.java` code ?

Comment: Posted in the main question. Thanks.

Comment: If you delete the fragment xml you must also delete the PlaceholderFragment class in your MainActivity.java. And also delete the if statement inside of the onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    }
```